# Polymer element inside shadow dom works, but is not styled

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am working on an app, which uses the custom element API (with webcomponents.js as polyfill). Inside of my element, I want to encapsulate everything in a shadow root. The HTML template of the polymer element seems to be imported correctly, however, styling is missing - unlike when I place the element outside, where styling seems to work:

```js
class TestWC extends HTMLElement {
  createdCallback() {
    console.log('created');
    var ShadowRoot = this.createShadowRoot();
    ShadowRoot.innerHTML = '<paper-input label="Inside shadow root"></paper-input>';
  }
}

var MyTestWC = document.registerElement('test-test', TestWC);
var MyTestWCInst = new MyTestWC();
document.querySelector('#placeholder').appendChild(MyTestWCInst);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/0.7.22/webcomponents.js"></script>
<paper-input label="Outside shadow root"></paper-input>
<p id="placeholder"></p>
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/paper-input/paper-input.html" />
```

[image: Example]

Question: Why does the original styling of polymer web components not work inside shadow root?

Edit: here is a Plunker; works in chrome only FTM.
http://plnkr.co/edit/rEibVckeUAqqrZljuVEy?p=preview

Comment: PS: What would be the preferred 'plunkr-like' platform for visualizing polymer-related issues? plunkr seems not to have the polymer components I use, or at least I did not find it?

Comment: My favorite service is [Codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/pbPBZB) if file assets are not needed. Otherwise, [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/y9UlCBgDzStBADeLBdyQ?p=preview).

Comment: Okay, found a CDN for paper-input. Added a plunker.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, but this might help http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/

Comment: Can you try same thing with some simple elements like `iron-image` or `iron-icon`.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use Polymer for your custom component?

Comment: Preferably I'd like to use plain webcomponents. FTM the webcomponents.js shim is a good way to add compliance for other platforms. As our product is not a website, we have the comfort to just support some of the most current browser versions - so soon I expect native webcomponents support, which is probably more performant for a big application.

Comment: So the question is: why is the style, which is probably part of the template (?) not applied, when the polymer component is used inside of a shadow dom...

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this is what you are wanted to achieve but this is what I did.

In x-foo.html I added the following in the template section. (paper-input)

```
<dom-module id="x-foo">
<template>
  <span>{{foo}}</span>
  <paper-input label="Inside shadow root"></paper-input>
</template>
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      foo: {
        type: String,
        value: 'Hello world'
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

In your main index.html I did the following:

```
//document.querySelector('#placeholder').appendChild(MyTestWCInst);

var elem = document.createElement("x-foo");
document.querySelector("#placeholder").appendChild(elem);
```

I don't think adding just plain innerHTML will trigger polymer to inject its magic.